# Use column values to fetch data from other dataset (sort of data transpose ) using Apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've two data-sets , one is source data and another is Metadata .

```
source data
============

name city state country
Ram  Agra     UP   India 
John Aligarh  UP   India
Shyam Merrut   UP   India
Isha Kanpur   UP   India

Metadata
=========

column_input   flag
name          Y
city          Y
state         N
country       N



FINAL OUTPUT
============
name city 
Ram  Agra      
John Aligarh  
Shyam Merrut   
Isha Kanpur
```

We required few columns from source based on meta information,we need to refer/read metadata data-set first, logic- flag should 'Y' ,here for 'city' and 'state' so we need to pull only these two columns from source data.

I'm able to get the column name from metadata data-set , now how i can pass this column name to to source to fetch corresponding columns data.

## current code

```
meta_data_read = LOAD  '/user/aidb'  USING PigStorage(',') AS (column_input,flag);

filter_flag  = FILTER meta_data_read by LOWER(TRIM(Flag)) == 'y' ;

gen_required_col = FOREACH filter_flag  GENERATE column_input;

dump gen_required_col ;

(city)
(state)
```

Comment: You have the same meta for all the rows or it can differs row by row?

Comment: same metadata for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all data rows has to processed against the same meta I would create a small (shell) script what process the meta file and respond the filed names comma separated. Than store it in a pig variable and use that variable to project the required fields.
Here's an example (NOTE: I did not created the shell script just declared the  PROJECT variable, but the script will be easy)

```
set pig.pretty.print.schema true;

%default PROJECT 'a,c'

data = LOAD 'SO/simple.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a:chararray, b:chararray, c:chararray, d:chararray);
DESCRIBE data;
dump data;
data_p = FOREACH data GENERATE
        $PROJECT;
DESCRIBE data_p;
DUMP data_p;
```

So the PROJECT variable contains the fields needs to be projected, and just use that in a FOREACH statement.
The describe results of this:

```
data: {
    a: chararray,
    b: chararray,
    c: chararray,
    d: chararray
}

data_p: {
    a: chararray,
    c: chararray
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.